# Which is the correct way to check if an element is present or displayed on a page with Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I'm testing a web application using Selenium WebDriver and I was wondering which is the proper method to check if the elements are present or displayed. I usually assert that all elements are present on the page but it also checks the hidden elements which in this case would also be necessary to check if the elements are displayed only when some action is done. For example I click a link and other fields and labels are displayed, while they were hidden before. In this case I should both check if the elements are present and also if they are or not displayed before and after some other element is clicked.

I was wondering which is the proper way to do this. Is it too much to check all the elements on the page ( assuming that I have some buttons, text-fields, labels, links etc. in the page)?

For the purpose of discussion I want to include some code snippets. To check that elements are present on the page I use the following snippet:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To check if an element is displayed I use the following snippet:

```
public boolean isElementDisplay(By by) {
    if (driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

One purpose of testing this application is to check if the elements exists and are displayed correctly. Am I doing the right thing here? Please give me your point of view. I've recently started working with Selenium WebDriver and being the only one in my company who does this...I don't have anyone to turn to. Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: I think there is no problem in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no problems with it, except if you call your "checkIfDisplayed" method on an element that doesn't exist in the first place, it will throw an exception. I would modify it to this:

```
public boolean checkIfDisplayed(By by) {
    if (isElementPresent(by) {
    if (driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

(This may not be code that compiles, I am a C# man, but you should see what I mean)

It may have a slight performance hit, but overall what you are doing is perfectly fine anyway.

Comment: To make it shorter I would simply write "return (isElementPresent(by) && driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed())" It's still not perfect though as it would cause the element to be searched for twice.

Comment: Yup you are absolutely right, lesser of two evils I'm afraid!

Answer (score 2):

To check for element's existence I'd rather use

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by)
{
   return driver.findElements(by).size() > 0
}
```

I don't really get the idea behind your checkIfDisplayed function. It returns the result returned by WebElemet's isDisplayed() method without adding any new functionality...

**EDIT**

So far Arran provided the best answer. Just to modify it a little bit:

```
public boolean checkIfDisplayed(By by)
{
   List<WebElemet> elements = driver.findElements(by);
   return ((elements.size() > 0) && (elements[0].isDisplayed()));
}
```

I believe however that it would be better to call isElementPresent and isDisplayed separately. In this way you will know why the test failed (if it was caused by element's existence or visibility)

Comment: This will bring back elements that are present in the markup/DOM but are not actually present to a user. After all, FindElement simply calls FindElements and does a `FirstOrDefault` on it.

Comment: @Arran Yes, you're right. But it will give the same result as in example provided by Michiru. Of course to check for visibility we will need something as you've demonstrated in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same approach (I mean the same methods). But it is important to understand two things.
Some element can be present but not visible.
So for the purpose to verify whether element is present we can call the method

```
 public boolean isElementPresent(By locatorKey) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(locatorKey);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
```

But the drawback of isElementPresent method it can point out elements in DOM model that are not visible  on the page and consequently are not accesssible with webDriver. So in that case additional check helps us:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(....)).isDisplayed()
```

Hope things come clear now)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your first method looks just fine.

The 2nd thus will give you trouble if the findElement-call will give you no result.

You should add a check if there is an element found and then check if it's displayed:

```
try {
      final WebElement elem = driver.findElement(by);
      elem.isDisplayed();
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
      return false;
    }
```

Also note: You are ignore the possibility that more than one element matches the criteria given by the by instance. See the [findElemts() method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can also **combine both the methods** as per your requirement as follows,

```
if(driver.findElements(By.LOCATOR).size()>0)
{
    if(driver.findElement(By.LOCATOR).isDisplayed())
    { print "Element is present and displayed"; }
    else
    { print "Element is present but not displayed"; }
} 
else
{ print "Element is not present"; }
```